# How to use bluetooth HID profile in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, hid

I want to make my android device act as input device to computers or any other devices using bluetooth hid or any profile.

As soon as i connect client device via bluetooth i should be able use my android device as mouse or keyboard just like wireless keypad or mouse.

After lot of research i come to know that android does not support HID profile so how can i achieve this is there any way to do it, I've got rooted device with me any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**  computer or any other should detect android device as wireless mouse instead of detecting it as android device so that i need not install any other application in controlling side of device.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get MAC Address (device_UUID):

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
byte[] macAddress = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < macAddress.length; byteIndex++) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X", macAddress[byteIndex]));
    if((byteIndex < macAddress.length - 1)){
        sb.append("-");
    }
}
```

Init cmd from android, like JsonObject:

```
mouseMove : {"cmd" : "mouseMove", "data" : [100, 200]}
mousePress : {"cmd" : "mousePress", "data" : [100]}
keyPress : {"cmd" : "keyPress", "data" : [100]}
```

Create connection between two device: 
For Android:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = Device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device_UUID_PC);
socket.connect();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeUTF(cmdJsonObject); // for example
socket.close();
```

For PC:

```
LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
localDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC); // Advertising the service
String url = "btspp://localhost:" + device_UUID_Android + ";name=BlueToothServer";
StreamConnectionNotifier server = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);
StreamConnection connection = server.acceptAndOpen(); // Wait until client connects
//=== At this point, two devices should be connected ===//
DataInputStream dis = connection.openDataInputStream();

String cmdJsonObject;
while (true) {
    cmdJsonObject = dis.readUTF();
}

connection.close();
```

Create service using Robot execute command:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
JsonObject jsonCMD = JsonObject(cmdJsonObject);
if(jsonCMD.containsKey("mouseMove")){
    JsonArray jsonData = jsonCMD.getJsonArray("data");
    int x = jsonData.getInt(0);
    int y = jsonData.getInt(1);
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
}
```

I hope it can help you!

Thank
@Victor Wong  : [Send data from android bluetooth to PC with bluecove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004087/send-data-from-android-bluetooth-to-pc-with-bluecove)

@Faisal Feroz : [Moving the cursor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231458/moving-the-cursor-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for your response. whatever you suggested is i already implemented that solution but i don't want to run any other application in computer, my computer should detect android device as wireless mouse instead of detecting it as android device.

Comment: Oh my god! That's impossible

Comment: It is possible by interacting with drivers.